# React-Native App terminated due to NSInternalInconsistencyException - 'This method must not be called before the JS thread is created'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I want to run my React-Native app in debug mode on my iPhone.
If run it in release there are no problems, it runs just fine.

When I try to run it in debug it first seems fine and builds the app. As expected it then installs to my iPhone and launches it. I can see the loading screen but the app won't finish loading. It just shows the loading screen and not the typical "connecting to metro server" or something like that

After a minute or two the app stops running in Expo and the error in the console says:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'This method must not be called before the JS thread is created'
```

references to `main.m` from the root project

Above the error are multiple connection attempts which all result in timeouts

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you figure out the issue here?

Comment: I had connection issues because my access point blocked the signal like in a guest network and it couldn’t connect to my macBook. Make sure you are in the same network and have guest network disabled for your devices

Comment: Ahhhhh. That might be it. My phone is on my cellular network, and my computer is on my WIFI.

Comment: Did someone manage to solve this issue?

Comment: When debugging react native in Xcode, turning off my Apple Watch seemed to help

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue while trying to achieve the same, could you please try following steps.

For your Xcode project > Product > Scheme > Edit scheme > Uncheck "Debug executable" checkbox and finally try running on debug mode on physical iPhone.

Comment: Well, it worked for me the way I described in my comment of my question. It were some issues with my wifi and reachability in my network. So it wasn't the fault of Xcode or my Code...